# LIBGDX android version runs well, But desktop version crashes

Tags: java, android, libgdx

**Error: Shows while running desktop version.**

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x03f2c930, pid=7236, tid=7088

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)

Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )

Problematic frame:

C  0x03f2c930

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:

F:\Advanced Android Gamin With LibGDX\Projects\Learning Libgdx Game Development\6047OS_02_2ndDraft-sources\demo-desktop\hs_err_pid7236.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:

http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.

See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

AL lib: alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

**END**

**Tutorial Reference book for me: Learning Libgdx Game Development**

I tried many solutions searching google, but nothing is working.

Comment: Did it work previously and recently stopped working, or are you trying to do an initial project setup?

Comment: It's initial project setup. @MartinCarney

Comment: Have you done a clean & build in your project? That can fix issues like this.